# Avoid importing a Python-3-only module when running unittests

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm working on some unittests for my project, Motor. These particular tests uses Python 3.3+ syntax features. They live in a submodule called "asyncio_tests":

https://github.com/mongodb/motor/tree/asyncio/test/asyncio_tests

In Python 2, "python setup.py test" throws an ImportError for this module because it can't parse the source code. I'd like to *skip* this module instead.

If the module could be imported in Python 2, I'd do something like this in asyncio_tests/**init**.py:

```
if sys.version_info[:2] < (3, 3):
    raise SkipTest('Need Python 3.3+')
```

But that code isn't executed because the file doesn't parse in Python 2. I looked at all the hooks I could see in Python 2.7's unittest module and couldn't find a way to skip *importing* a module.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is putting these test functions in a string or separate file, and conditionally `exec()`ing this string...